# XPath check multiple child node text

Tags: xml, xpath

I am working OVAL(Open Vulnerability and Assessment Language). There I am checking xml config file using xpath.

XML file is like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
</web>
```

I want to check inside `init-param` `param-name` must contain `debug` and `param-value` also must contain `0`.

I am writing xpath like this

```
<xpath datatype="string" operation="equals">/*[local-name()="web-app"]/*[local-name()="servlet"]/*[local-name()="init-param"]/*[local-name()="param-name"][text()="debug"][local-name()="param-value"][text()="0"]</xpath>
```

But it's not woking, Is there any other way to check?

Answer (score 1):

try this locator:

```
//init-param[./param-name[contains(text(),'debug')]][./param-value[contains(text(),'0')]]
```

logic is simple:
locator to get element with special attribute looks like this: `tag[attribute]`, you can get elements with multiple attributes using it too: `tag[attribute1][attribute2]` or `tag[attribute1 and attribute2]`